# Can we share application in blackberry without the use of jad files

Tags: blackberry, upload, distribute

I need to know whether we can install and share blackberry application without using .jad files and make it just one .cod files as a distribution package to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clarification, we are talking about BB7 applications here, not BB10.

You ask whether it is possible to **install and share** a Blackberry application, without using a jad.

In addition to OTA installation (which is where a jad file comes in), you can install applications using the Desktop Manager or some low level application such a javaloader.  These use the cod files, from a PC.

What I am not clear on is what you mean by share. Can you explain what you expect to be able to do?

One other comment, another answer suggests that you can use CodeModulemanager.  Be aware that you can't use CodeModuleManager unless you write an application, and if you do, you sort of have a chicken and egg situation.  Before you can use CodeModuleManager to install Applications, then you need to have the application that includes the CodeModuleManager code installed - in other words, an installer application.