# Sending cod files via bluetooth in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, bluetooth

In android device where .apk files are shared and send via bluetooth and then install on device.

Can similar thing is available in Blackberry devices lower versions below OS 10 ?
Can we send or share and install .cod applications via bluetooth in blackberry.
Please do let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no OS (standard) supplied method to do this.

I think this is a variation on this question

[Can we share application in blackberry without the use of jad files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229953/can-we-share-application-in-blackberry-without-the-use-of-jad-files)

and as with that question, using CodeModuleManager (as suggested in another answer) requires an application that is already on the phone.  In this situation, this installer application would have to know how to open a Bluetooth connection, and read the data and then create the new Application using CodeModuleManager  I suspect this solution also assumes that there is another application that is sending the file, from a device what is paired with the phone.  Is this a workable solution?